# Как упомянуть участника сервера, которого я упомянул до этого в discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Допустим, я хочу *обнять* человека.
пишу "!обнять @id".
Как мне сделать так, чтобы бот упомянул того человека, которого до этого упомянул я?
Бот должен вывести что-то такое: "@мой id обнимает @другой id"
Много чего перепробовал, бот в основном просто не реагирует на команды.

```py
    import discord
    import random
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
    
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
    
            return
        if message.content.startswith(f'!привет'):
            await message.channel.send(f'Привет, {message.autor.mention}')


        if message.content.startswith(f'!пока'):
            await message.channel.send(f'До встречи, {message.author.mention}! Будем тебя ждать!')
        strings = [
            'ссылка на GIF',
            'ссылка на GIF',
            'ссылка на GIF',
            'ссылка на GIF'
        ]

            await message.channel.send(random.choice(strings))
```

Таких команд много, но они одинаковые.

Answer (score 1):

Часть команды. На всякий случай, ниже скину вам полный код бота

```
@bot.command()
async def обнять(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):

    if member == None:
        return
        
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} обнял {member.mention}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True) # case_insensitive=True - команды не регистрозависимые


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def обнять(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):

    if member == None:
        return
        
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} обнял {member.mention}")

bot.run('')
```

Пример команд.

```
@bot.command()
async def обнять(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Привет {ctx.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Как мне вставить команду в свой код? У меня стандартный код, как в документации (команды я не вставлял, ибо они заняли бы все допустимые символы).
`import discord
import random


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


client.run('токен')`

Все команды постороены по принципу
`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(f'!привет'):
        await message.channel.send(f'привет, {message.author.mention}!'`

Comment: прикрепите свой код в вопрос. Я вам на всякий случай, ниже оставил полный код для бота, можете использовать его.

Comment: Я прикрепил свой код.

Comment: Ясно. Вы зачем то сами команды крепите к on_message что в корне неверно.
Тут думаю нет смысла разбирать всё это.

Скопируйте мой код и все команды перенесите в функции

Comment: ответ поправил. Скопируйте мой код  и вставьте свои команды.